# How do I control which version Yarn chooses for a dependency's peerDependency when using Yarn workspaces/nohoist?

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I have a Yarn workspace with two packages, `watermelon-web` and `watermelon-native`, which use the latest version of `react-redux` but different versions of `react`. The issue is that I am not able to control which version of `react` Yarn chooses for the **peerDependency** of `react-redux`.

Workspace `package.json`:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "workspaces": {
        "packages": [
            "watermelon-web",
            "watermelon-native"
        ],
        "nohoist": [            
            "**/watermelon-native/react-redux"
        ]
    }
}
```

(the nohoist is required to prevent a runtime error)

`watermelon-web/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "watermelon-web",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3"
  }
}
```

`watermelon-native/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "watermelon-native",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3"
  }
}
```

Meanwhile, `react-redux` has a peerDependency `"react": "^16.8.3"`.

**What I want to happen:** After Yarn install, `watermelon-native/node_modules/react-redux/node_modules` does NOT contain `react`. This way, when, `react-redux` tries to import `react` at runtime, it would get `react@16.8.3` from `watermelon-native/node_modules`.

**What actually happens:** Yarn installs `react@16.12.0` in `watermelon-native/node_modules/react-redux/node_modules`. When I run `watermelon-native`, React reports an "Invalid hook call" because `watermelon-native` is using `react@16.8.3` but `react-redux` is using `react@16.12.0`. (Both packages must be using the exact same instance of React for React hooks to work.)

**How do I get Yarn to work the way I want it to?**

I have tried using [Yarn selective dependency resolutions](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/), AKA the "resolutions" element in `package.json`, in almost every way possible, but there was no observable change in Yarn's behavior. For example, I tried adding

```
"resolutions": {
    "**/watermelon-native/react-redux/react": "16.8.3"
}
```

to the workspace `package.json`.

Two easy "solutions" would be to use the same React version in all of my packages (would require downgrading `watermelon-web` to `16.8.3`) or to forgo using Yarn workspaces. Each of these has drawbacks that I'd like to avoid if possible.

(Note: My code examples come from React Native development, but the question itself applies only to Yarn and has nothing to do with React. `react` and `react-redux` could be replaced by any other packages that have sufficiently similar dependencies.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the answer to the question is just "Yarn doesn't work like that", for the time being at least.

In the meantime, I found a simple workaround. Since deleting the `react` folder from `watermelon-native/node_modules/react-redux/node_modules/react` fixes the issue, I added a `postinstall` script that deletes that `react` folder after every install.

My PowerShell script (use whatever shell you like)

```
function TryRemove-Path($path) {
    if(Test-Path $path) {
        Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $path
    }
}


TryRemove-Path("$PSScriptRoot/node_modules/react-redux/node_modules/react")
```

This is pretty hacky, but even the Expo project relies on [postinstall magic](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-yarn-workspaces) to get their React Native apps to work with yarn workspaces. So maybe this workaround is not so bad.